# How to concatenate a unicode string literal with bytes?

Tags: c, string, unicode, byte, concatenation

Considering this USB string descriptor:

```
#define USB_PRODUCT_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_LENGTH (34U)
#define USB_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STRING (0x03U)

uint8_t UsbProductString[USB_PRODUCT_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_LENGTH] = {
    USB_PRODUCT_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_LENGTH,
    USB_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STRING,
    'C', 0x00U,
    'O', 0x00U,
    'M', 0x00U,
    'P', 0x00U,
    'O', 0x00U,
    'S', 0x00U,
    'I', 0x00U,
    'T', 0x00U,
    'E', 0x00U,
    ' ', 0x00U,
    'D', 0x00U,
    'E', 0x00U,
    'V', 0x00U,
    'I', 0x00U,
    'C', 0x00U,
    'E', 0x00U,
};
```

Is there any way to represent it in an easier to read fashion? Possibly using the `u""` string syntax?

Comment: Post `USB_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STRING` definition.

Comment: Are these wide characters (`wchar_t`), some Unicode encoding, or just ASCII with interlaced zeros?

Comment: @e0k Since `wchar_t` might not be 2 `uint8_t` it does not look like wide characters.  Maybe UTF16-LE?  László Monda - please provide more detail.

Comment: @chux Just posted `USB_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STRING` definition.

Comment: @e0k Looks like USB uses UTF-16LE.

Answer (score 0):

> How to concatenate a unicode string literal with bytes?

I do not think there is a way to solve the title problem.

> Is there any way to represent it in an easier to read fashion? Possibly using the u"" string syntax?

See no easy way to clearly cope with concatenating the 3 fields.

Recall that `u"some text"` is used with `char16_t` and may/may not represent `UTF-16` encoding.

Perhaps simple use a 3 field type?

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <uchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//#define USB_PRODUCT_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_LENGTH (34U)
#define USB_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STRING 1
#define UPS_SIZE(S) (sizeof(uint8_t) + sizeof(uint8_t) + sizeof(S) - 2 /*null character*/)

typedef struct {
  uint8_t length;
  uint8_t descriptor_type;
  char16_t descriptor[127];  // 127 Maximum length
} USBProductString_T;

int main(void) {
  #if __STDC_UTF_16__ == 1
    puts("values of type char16_t are UTF-16 encoded.");
  #else
    puts("values of type char16_t are not known to be UTF-16 encoded.");
    return 0;
  #endif


  #define COMPOSITE_DEVICE u"COMPOSITE DEVICE"
  USBProductString_T UsbProductString = 
    { UPS_SIZE(COMPOSITE_DEVICE), USB_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STRING, COMPOSITE_DEVICE };


  printf("%u %u %zu\n", 1U*UsbProductString.length, 1U*UsbProductString.descriptor_type, 
      sizeof UsbProductString);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
values of type char16_t are UTF-16 encoded.
34 1 256
```

---

To further address OP additional restrictions - space:

Decouple constants from active type.   Use `char16_t[]` to form `UsbProductString` and then make a special post-initialize/copy/compare/create function to use it.  Various approaches depending on unstated design constraints.

```
static char16_t UsbProductString[] = u"COMPOSITE DEVICE";

void FormString(uint8_t buf[], const char16_t *s) {
  unsigned bi = 0,si = 0;
  buf[++bi] = USB_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STRING
  while (s[si]) {
    buf[++bi] = s[si] % 256;
    buf[++bi] = s[si] / 256;
    si++;
  }
  buf[0] == ++bi;
}

uint8_t buf[sizeof UsbProductString - 2  + 2];  // string has an unneeded null character
FormString(buf, UsbProductString);
Send(buf);
```

---

Your post wants a  structure with 1) flexible array member and 2)  declare it with an *initialized* value.  As I understand C, this is not possible.  You are right to consider `UsbProductString[]` an array and try to wedge the first fields in a part of a string, but that sacrifices readability - trying to create "UTF-16" `uint8_t` data.

Comment: This looks pretty tight, thanks! My only gripe is that the `descriptor` field always occupies 254 bytes. This is quite a waste on microcontrollers. Any ways to get around this?